# Substitute the removed pivot table feature in ms access

Tags: ms-access

I am new to ms access; I am working on a database in an administrative setting. I need to filter office titles by bureau while also counting the number of said titles in each bureau.Any ideas on how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Please show the tables and fields with sample data, the query you already tried and show us the result you expect regarding the sample data.

Comment: Sounds like a simple aggregate (GROUP BY) query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Crosstab query (a.k.a. SQL TRANSFORM/PIVOT query) provides some pivot table features.  Whereas a pivot table provides dynamic features (allowing real-time drill down, column selection and criteria specification), the Crosstab provides a single view of the data.  The "drill-down" capability can be handled by other Crosstab queries with more specific WHERE selection and finer pivot intervals.  The Crosstab does not support multiple pivoting columns, but one can combine results of multiple Crosstabs into a combined query using UNION statements and other techniques.

As expressed in [other forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-access/pivot-table-view-in-access-2016/4f48eec8-2f47-4627-85b6-6f9727974f22?auth=1), you can export the data to Excel and use pivot tables there.